# How does responsive design work in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I am coming to `Angular 2` from a bootstrap position, as in attaching classes like `container-fluid`, `row`, `col-md-10` and that kind of thing.

I have found a multitude of resources that talk about `bootstrap` in Angular 2 like `ng2-bootstrap` and on the `angular.io` tutorial, but nothing that I recognize or understand as the traditional grid style bootstrap I know.

If someone could connect the dots I would appreciate it. I think there is some key point that I am missing. Like is the attaching classes method of boostrap like `col-md-10` and `col-offset` irrelevant in `Angular 2`? If I wanted to create a responsive site with two columns or something like that, how would that work?

Comment: the ui framework like bootstrap and angular 2 are as such independent, has nothing to do with each other, though they are mostly used with each other

Comment: Bootstrap isn't really affected by the JS framework you use. `ng2-bootstrap` is just an Angular 2 widget library that assumes you are already using the base bootstrap styles. `ng2-bootstrap` and angular 2 have nothing to do with responsive design

Answer (score 3):

I think you misunderstood about `ng2-bootstrap`, It is native Angular2 directives for `Bootstrap`, works with `Bootstrap` **3** and **4-alfa** So for CSS class, still you need bootstrap in your application with `ng2-bootstrap`.

It mainly provides `directives` to make our life easier like `UI bootstrap` in `angular 1.x`. But for styling you need bootstrap anyhow.

If you are trying `sass` check out this [link](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-use-Bootstrap-3-and-Sass-and-ng2-bootstrap)

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using https://github.com/angular/flex-layout from the angular team if you are only after layout directives.

Its straight forward and you won't need to import bootstrap.